# mariadb will not start following a power cut

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Everything was fine until a power cut and now mariadb will not start.  the below is logged in /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log.

- 200927 18:01:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases
  from /var/lib/mysql /usr/libexec/mysqld: symbol lookup error:
- /usr/libexec/mysqld: undefined symbol:
  _ZN14JOIN_CACHE_BNL28get_lext_candidate_for_ma|chEv
- 200927 18:01:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended

Regards

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this, but not fully sure how.

I did have other issues reported originally as warning:

- Found row where the auto_increment column has the value 0
- client is using or hasn't closed the table properly

I ran

- myisamchk -s /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI
- myisamchk -r --update-state /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI

I did try mysqlcheck first but it would not work as the service was not up.

It appears all I needed to do afterward was another system reboot and that cleared the last error.

Regards

Matt